# Add dynamic content in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a form result that needs to be processed in a pdf.

I am considering using tcpdf.

It has this code in an example:

```
// Set some content to print
$html = <<<EOD
<h1>Welcome to </h1>
etc..
EOD;

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
```

Now I want in the html section, something like:

```
$html = <<<EOD
<h1>Welcome to !</h1><table>
$resultcvp = $conn->query($sqlcvp);
if ($resultcvp->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $resultcvp->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["PARTNUMBER"]. " </td><td> " . $row["DESCRIPTION"]. "</td><td> " . $row["AMOUNT"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
};
</table>
EOD;

};
```

But anything I try, I cannot load this while statement result in the pdf.
Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: welcome to SO! have a look at tcpdf documentations, since it has a good documentations!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do loops and queries while you are in the HEREDOC section of your code. You will need to build up your HTML as you go through the loop.

```
$html = '<h1>Welcome to !</h1><table>';
$resultcvp = $conn->query($sqlcvp);
if ($resultcvp->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $resultcvp->fetch_assoc()) {
        $html .= '<tr><td>' . $row["PARTNUMBER"]. ' </td><td> ' . $row["DESCRIPTION"]. '</td><td> ' . $row["AMOUNT"]. '</td></tr>';
    }
};
$html .= '</table>';
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
```